# Is it possible to have Intellisense in XAML when using Caliburn automatic datacontext?

Tags: winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

When you use Caliburn, your View gets its datacontext set dynamically at runtime by convention. However, it would be nice if you could also set it in the designer so that VS and the compiler could verify it and provide you with Intellisense without interfering with the Caliburn binding.

If I set it myself, like:

```
DataContext="MyApp.MainViewModel"
```

I don't get the Caliburn binding.

Is it possible to set it just for the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can take advantage of **[Design-Time](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design-Time%20Support&referringTitle=Documentation)** support provided by Caliburn.Micro.

> You have to set a Desinger-DataContext and tell CM to enable its magic in your view XAML:
>
> ```
> xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
> xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
> xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CaliburnDesignTimeData.ViewModels"
> xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
> mc:Ignorable="d" 
> d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainPageViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
> cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True"
> ```
>
> For this to work, the ViewModel must have a default constructor. If this isn't suitable, > you can also use a ViewModelLocator for your design-time ViewModel creation.

All of this is taken from the documentation page on [**Design-Time Support**](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design-Time%20Support&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the Bind.AtDesignTime and the default constructor. And the ability to read their documentation, naturally...

Comment: @RobKent You are welcome, they were written recently so you could have missed them.